# why isn't java.lang.Throwable an abstract class?

Tags: java, class-design, throwable

Possible duplicate: [why-is-java-lang-throwable-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890311/)

Hi! I doesn't understand why Throwable isn't abstract class. I see only one use case for these: in logging systems for figure out call hierarchy. But it can be some static method for this or other class. So, why?)

Thanks.

**upd**

from  java.util.logging.LogRecord

```
// Get the stack trace.
StackTraceElement stack[] = (new Throwable()).getStackTrace();
```

Why it can't be `Throwable.getStackTrace();`  or as in  java.lang.Thread

```
(new Exception()).getStackTrace();
```

In this way we can avoid `throw new Throwable();`

**upd2**
from javadoc

> The Throwable class is the superclass
>   of all errors and exceptions in the
>   Java language.

So, as a superclass it should be abstract, imho. Using it for getting stacktrace isn't good case by this definition.

Comment: Where does it ever "throw new Throwable();" ?  Not sure you need to avoid something which never happens. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey : Somebody can write it. API should avoid bad using (not only my IMHO).

Comment: @Stas, It is highly unlikely to compile accidently as it is checked exception. You have to handle it or add it to the throws clause. I think that is avoidance enough.  Not convinced there is a serious problem which needs another solution.

Comment: @Stas, My IDE also has a warning "Prohibited Exception thrown" This can be changed to a compiler error level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is java.lang.Throwable a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890311/why-is-java-lang-throwable-a-class)

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question. Being a superclass isn't a sufficient reason to want it to be abstract.

Comment: @EJP, If we use class only as superclass, we can use only protected constructor. If we doesn't create its instances - why it shouldn't be abstract?

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question. Why *should* it be abstract? Who said that classes used only as superclasses should be abstract? This is not a hard and fast principle. The only Java language rule about abstract classes is that classes with abstract methods must be declared as abstract. You're trying to create a new rule, and you haven't given anything that approaches a justification. And who said we only use it as a superclass in the first place?

Comment: @EJP, to get answer for your first question I start new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311271/. About second. I think we should use classes only in use cases that docs gives as. In other hand, API should avoid using classes in wrong ways.

Comment: You're still begging the question. You are defining something as a 'wrong way' without any actual justification, and then using that as the basis for your conclustion. It doesn't follow, and your premiss is invalid. There is nothing in the Javadoc that prevents using Throwable directly.

Comment: @EJP, ok. I give up) You are right. But if It was I why develop this API, I've made it in other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I doesn't understand why Throwable
>   isn't abstract class.

The answer is clearly stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890311/).

> Why it can't be
>   Throwable.getStackTrace(); or as in
>   java.lang.Thread

Quite simply, the `getStackTrace()` calls the `getOurStackTrace()` method which is non-static. If `getStackTrace()` was static, so should `getOurStackTrace()`. This won't happen as `printStackTrace()` method uses the `getOurStackTrace()`. This is elaborated in the JavaDoc:

> Provides programmatic access to the
>   stack trace information printed by
>   printStackTrace().

Source for java.lang.Throwable:

```
 public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
        return (StackTraceElement[]) getOurStackTrace().clone();
    }
```

<strike>Also, if you read the code of `getOurStackTrace()` method, you'll see it calls the following method:</strike>

```
private native int getStackTraceDepth();
```

As far as I know, [`native`](http://java.sun.com/docs/glossary.html) cannot be static (I may be wrong).

Comment: Native methods can be static (see pretty much any method in `java.lang.StrictMath`).

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, it's on the `Throwable` class in the JDK (mine is 1.6.0-21, it was introduced since JDK 4 I believe?)

Comment: If native can be static, I think `Throwable.getStackTrace()` better idea than `new Throwable().getStackTrace()`

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, java.lang.Thread also has this method. It is marked @since 1.4. Not sure there was a JDK 4. ;)

Comment: @Stas, Throwable.getStackTrace() isn't static because it gets/populates the stack trace for the throwable. (Where it was first created)  Calling it more than once, in different places won't give you a different result.

Comment: @Stas: They would have completely different semantics if it were static.  `getStackTrace()` for a subclass of `Throwable` is supposed to return the stacktrace at the point that `fillInStackTrace()` was called, which is at construction of the `Throwable` typically.  Calling it statically would have to return whatever the stacktrace is *at the time of the method call* which would be much less useful (e.g. it would print the stacktrace to the logging code, not to where the exception occurred).

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, the `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` method effectively calls `private native static StackTraceElement[][] dumpThreads(Thread[] threads);` so it's still done natively.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, @Mark Peters, `Throwable` can initialize itself by calling this static method, cant it?

Comment: @Stas, This method isn't used for good reasons. It initializes the stack trace lazily to improve performance. Most of the time, this array isn't needed, e.g. catch(Exception e) but taking the stack trace when it is used isn't very useful either.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, Not sure how your point relates to what I said.

Comment: @Stas: A static method has no reference to an "instance", so no instance can be initialized from a static method unless you pass the instance in.  If you're wondering if the data could be stored statically, the answer is yes, but that is absolutely horrible.  It would prevent Throwable from being used from multiple threads (without jumping through dozens of hoops), for starters.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, sorry...I got lost somehow... :)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, still a good point. Another useful method worth knowing about.

Comment: @Mark Peters : I mean smt like `Throwable(){ stackTrace = stackTrace();}  public static StackTrace stackTrace()`. Why it's bad?

Comment: @Stas: Well, for starters it would make almost no sense to have such a static method in `Throwable`, since at this point it has nothing to do with throwing/catching, and everything to do with the state of the `Thread`.  And as has been explored, Thread already *has* a method for retrieving the stack trace.

Comment: @Mark Peters, I got lost too. Let's put `native getStackTrace()` into `Thread` and will use it in `abstract class Throwable`. why these solution is bad? PS : off course now API frozen.

Answer (score 1):

I use it quite often for logging, so I am glad it isn't abstract.  There is a method to get the call stack, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() but this returns a StackTraceElement[] which isn't very useful for logging.

EDIT:

```
StackTraceElement[] stes = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Note: this method also works to get a stack trace of another thread which can be handy.

Comment: Can you show how do you use it? In java.util.logging it used to get StackTraceElement[] "(new Throwable()).getStackTrace();"

Comment: I don't think making Throwable abstract would really stop you...you could either do `new Throwable(){}.printStackTrace()` for throwaway logging, or for logging that you keep you should probably be using the cleaner `Thread` solution anyway (or at least a library method that wraps it).

Comment: @Mark, logging StackTraceElement[] is tedious to make readable.  You don't want it to be split by other log messages for example. esp another stack trace.

Comment: fair enough, though for non-throwaway logging I would expect one to be using a logging framework that does all this for you anyway (all logging frameworks I've seen have methods to log a Throwable directly).